# Regex using the AND NOT operator

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm looking for a regular expression that I find in the text, the words "ata de audiência" OR "termo de audiência", and find "inconcilia" AND "reclamante" AND "reclamada", and do NOT find the word "sentença"

```
if(re.search(r'ata de audiência' or r'termo de audiência') and r'inconcilia' and r'reclamada' and r'reclamante' and not r'sentença', content.read())):
            key_content = True
```

I tried to do it this way.. i can find the words, but when I use the  "AND NOT" operator, the regular expression does not work

ps: there are words in portuguese

Comment: Please create a minimal example that is easily reproducible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for that.

```
text = content.read()

if ('ata de audiência' in text or 'termo de audiência' in text) \
    and 'inconcilia' in text and 'reclamada' in text \
    and 'reclamante' in text and not 'sentença' in text:
        key_content = True
```

Comment: >when using non-ascii characters you have to prefix your strings with u'. | That's true only for Python 2; the question is tagged as Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is not complete enough to comment in detail but the first issue is misunderstanding that argument you've passed to `re.search()`.

The following code is a boolean expression:

```
r'ata de audiência' or r'termo de audiência'
```

Python interprets this as "use the first string, if not None or not empty, or else the second".

On the console:

```
>>> r'ata de audiência' or r'termo de audiência'
'ata de audiência'
```

Likewise with `and` and `not`:

```
>>> r'inconcilia' and r'reclamada'
'reclamada'

>>> r'inconcilia' and r'reclamada' and r'reclamante' and not r'sentença'
False
```

You need to provide a small standalone example. Often the act of preparing that example will get you a long way to answering the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how regex works. I'd suggest you read more about it if you really want to use it.

For your needs, the `in` keyword would be more appropriate. It returns `True` if the substring is in the string, or `False` if it isn't. You could chain those with `and` and `or` commands, or you could do something like this:

```
contents_text = content.read()
if any(word in contents_text for word in ['ata de audiência', 'termo de audiência']) 
    and all(word in context_text for word in ['inconcilia', 'reclamada', 'reclamante'])
    and 'sentença' not in context_text:
        key_content = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(
0 <= re.search('((ata de audiência){1}||(termo de audiência){1})&&(inconcilia){1}&&(reclamada){1}&&(reclamante){1}&&(sentença){0}', content.read())
){
 key_content = True
}
```